# Images not loading until the page is refreshed

Tags: ajax, media

The links are identical, the path is correct, the image is there,but i have to refresh the page for the image to show, i am suspecting the "itok" parameter might be causing the problem,. It was working fine at the beginning, at some point during the development i started having the problem.

Any help with be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue,I need to refresh the image to upload.How did you fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried  the [Image Allow Insecure Derivatives](https://drupal.org/project/image_allow_insecure_derivatives) module?

> Provides a user interface to allow Drupal to bypass the token security check when generating image derivatives.
>
> #### Details
>
> [Drupal 7.20](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes) comes with a security fix that changes all image derivative URLs generated by Drupal to append a token as a query string. ("Image derivatives" are copies of images which the Drupal Image module automatically creates based on configured image styles; for example, thumbnail, medium, large, etc.)
>
> s an example, links that previously pointed to a URL like: /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/field/image/example.png
>
> will now point to a URL like: /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/field/image/example.png?itok=zD_VaCaD
>
> For more information on the security improvement, [visit the release notes](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes).
>
> This is a fantastic security improvement, but in certain cases, has some ramifications. This module provides a configuration setting in order to toggle whether or not Drupal bypasses that token check.

Comment: I have the same issue,I use tokens in image paths and I need to refresh the image so as to appear.I tried the above module but no luck,the issue remains.Anymore suggestions?thanks